# How to add texture to bitmap in Java (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have created an app that allows generates a random gradient background to be set as a device wallpaper. I would like to give the user the option to add textures to the wallpaper. I have found the method to do that in xml but not in Java.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);


        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
                    new int[]{colorsArray1, colorsArray2, colorsArray3}, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        Paint paintGradient = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paintGradient.setShader(shader);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paintGradient);
```

The above code generates a bitmap that is a gradient with three colours. Is there any way to add textures to it? Is it even possible?

[This is kinda what my goal is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shsbF.jpg)

Thanks in advance folks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should draw such textures manually. For example you can create semitransparent gradient shader and draw multiple rectangles along the both diagonals with some rotation and shift for each rectangle.